# get all mobile number accociated with one contact android

Tags: android, contactscontract

I have contact added to my addressbook which has mutiple number like below.[image]

I want to fetch all 3 number of "User" using  `ContactsContract` content uri.
By using below code i got only one contact.

```
 Cursor cursorAddressBook = mContentResolver.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursorAddressBook != null) {
        while (cursorAddressBook.moveToNext()) {

            String dataName = cursorAddressBook.getString(cursorAddressBook.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String dataNumber = cursorAddressBook.getString(cursorAddressBook.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            int dataType = cursorAddressBook.getInt(cursorAddressBook.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA2));
            String contactId = cursorAddressBook.getString(cursorAddressBook.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));

            Log.e("last updat Name last", dataName);
            Log.e("last updated No last", dataNumber);
            Log.e("last updated Type last", dataType);


        }
        cursorAddressBook.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this [blogpost](http://techblogon.com/read-multiple-phone-numbers-from-android-contacts-list-programmatically/)   If a contact has multiple phone numbers, then You can retrieve all phone numbers and other details using Android’s inbuilt classes (Cursor and ContactsContract ) in Android.  And you need to retrieve the contact number based on phone type like (TYPE_MOBILE, TYPE_HOME ect)

```
{
    Cursor cursor = cntx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    Integer contactsCount = cursor.getCount(); // get how many contacts you have in your contacts list 
    if (contactsCount > 0)
    {
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
            {
                //the below cursor will give you details for multiple contacts
                Cursor pCursor = cntx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                                                                new String[]{id}, null);
                // continue till this cursor reaches to all phone numbers which are associated with a contact in the contact list  
                while (pCursor.moveToNext())
                 {
                      int phoneType         = pCursor.getInt(pCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                      //String isStarred        = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STARRED));
                      String phoneNo    = pCursor.getString(pCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                      //you will get all phone numbers according to it's type as below switch case.
                      //Logs.e will print the phone number along with the name in DDMS. you can use these details where ever you want.
                      switch (phoneType)
                      {
                            case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                                Log.e(contactName + ": TYPE_MOBILE", " " + phoneNo);
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                                Log.e(contactName + ": TYPE_HOME", " " + phoneNo);
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                                Log.e(contactName + ": TYPE_WORK", " " + phoneNo);
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE:
                                Log.e(contactName + ": TYPE_WORK_MOBILE", " " + phoneNo);
                                break;            
                            case Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                                Log.e(contactName + ": TYPE_OTHER", " " + phoneNo);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                      }
              }
              pCursor.close();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for fetching all the phone numbers of one contact

```
 String id, name;
 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
 String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
 Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, sortOrder);

 if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

     while (cur.moveToNext()) {
         id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
         name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
         Log.i(tag, "Id is " + id + "\t Name is" + name);

         if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

             Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,

                 null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] {
                     id
                 }, null);

             // this second loop will retrieve all the contact numbers for a paricular contact id 
             while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                 // Do something with phones

                 int phNumber = pCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                 String phn = pCur.getString(phNumber);

                 Log.i("phn number", phn);
             }
             pCur.close();

         }

     }

 }
```